# RxJava: Converting callback to reactive stream by nesting event source inside Observable.create(), vs storing ObservableEmmiter

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Whenever people talk about converting callback to RxJava style, all the answers I have seen so far here or elsewhere suggest to nest the callback like this:

```
Observable.create(emitter -> {
            button.setOnClickListner(View.OnClickListner(){
                   void onClick(...) {
                     emitter.onNext(value);
                   }
            }})
```

But then the following also works, but never mentioned.

```
public class Something{
    static ObservableEmitter<Object> myemitter;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       doS();                
       myemitter.onNext(12);
    }
    
    static void doS() {
         Observable.create(emitter -> {
            myemitter = emitter;
        }).map( v ->{
            System.out.println("this is Map function");
            return v ;
        }).subscribe(v -> {
            System.out.println(v);
        });
    }
}
```

The significance of the second example is that a particular listener is no longer tied down to the reactive chain. Meaning I could just pass around ObservableEmitter to any listener and just call .onNext().

Is there any unforeseen side effect or downside to doing like the second approach?

Comment: it's not thread safe and `myemitter` is static, that means you will have a lot of floating bugs

Comment: myemitter here is static variable because that example here is what I had at the moment of writing. So, I guess thread safety is enough of a reason then. Consider adding the comment as an answer.